# List all entries below top level 1 in a structure section (level 2 or 3 or 4 ...)

Tags: entries

I have a structure section with 3 levels.
I d like to list all entries below 1st level.
I see `ancestorDist` or `descendantDist` but I m not sure it is what I need...
https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries

I see I can select multiple levels:
`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('library').limit(10).level(2,3) %}`
but I d like something like:
`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('library').limit(10).level(>1) %}`

Comment: What do you mean by `above first level`? level one is the top level. There is nothing above it.

Comment: sorry I mean below in fact, all entries from levels 2 or 3 or 4...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright. you can just exclude the top level entries with `not`:

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('library').level('not 1') %}`